# Could not find resource node. but node enabled?

Tags: 7, ajax, services

In my app, I am fetching data, editing and re-submitting it. That's where I am getting `Could not find resource node.`. However, `node` is enabled under `Resources`. Besides, I am not getting any errors fetching data. I was following [this guide](http://tylerfrankenstein.com/code/android-app-with-drupal-7-services-phonegap-and-jquery-mobile). How to handle this situation? My code is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.rejicast.com/services/user/token.json',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(token) {
        localStorage.token = token.token;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://www.rejicast.com/services/system/connect.json',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function(r) {
                r.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", localStorage.token)
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://www.rejicast.com/oyuncularim.json',
                    type: 'get',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        uid_raw: localStorage.uid
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        nid = data.nodes[0].node.nid;
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                        $("#otherpicture").attr("src", data.nodes[0].node.field_fotograflar.src);
                        /*
                        $("#otherpicture-2").attr("src", data.nodes[1].node.field_fotograflar.src);
                        $("#otherpicture-3").attr("src", data.nodes[2].node.field_fotograflar.src);
                        $("#otherpicture-4").attr("src", data.nodes[3].node.field_fotograflar.src);
                        $("#otherpicture-5").attr("src", data.nodes[4].node.field_fotograflar.src);
                        */
                        $("#name").val(data.nodes[0].node.title);
                        $("#tckn").val(data.nodes[0].node.field_tc_kimlik_no);
                        $("#dob").val(data.nodes[0].node.field_dogum_tarihi_1);
                        $("#email").val(data.nodes[0].node.field_e_posta);
                        $("#tel").val(data.nodes[0].node.field_telefon);
                        $("#tel2").val(data.nodes[0].node.field_telefon_2);
                        $("#address").val(data.nodes[0].node.field_adres);
                        $("#city option:contains('"+data.nodes[0].node.field_yasadigi_sehir+"')").prop("selected", "selected");
                        $("#gender option[innerHTML="+data.nodes[0].node.field_cinsiyet+"]").prop("selected", "selected");
                        $("#chest option:contains('"+data.nodes[0].node.field_sehir+"')").prop("selected", "selected");
                        $("#waist option:contains('"+data.nodes[0].node.field_bel+"')").prop("selected", "selected");
                        $("#thigh option:contains('"+data.nodes[0].node.field_kalca+"')").prop("selected", "selected");
                        $("#weight option:contains('"+data.nodes[0].node.field_kilo+"')").prop("selected", "selected");
                        $("#height option:contains('"+data.nodes[0].node.field_boy+"')").prop("selected",true);
                        $("#eyecolour option:contains('"+data.nodes[0].node.field_goz_rengi+"')").prop("selected", "selected");
                        $("#skincolour option:contains('"+data.nodes[0].node.field_ten_rengi+"')").prop("selected", "selected");
                        $("#shoesize").val(data.nodes[0].node.field_ayak_no);
                        $("#education").val(data.nodes[0].node.field_egitim_duzeyi);
                        $("#training").val(data.nodes[0].node.field_oyunculuk_egitimleri);
                        $("#skills").val(data.nodes[0].node.field_beceriler);
                        $("#languages").val(data.nodes[0].node.field_diller);
                        $("#personal").val(data.nodes[0].node.field_kisisel);
                        $(".videolink").val(data.nodes[0].node.field_videolar);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
$("#edit").on("click", function() {
    ActivityIndicator.show("Face in Cast", "Düzeltme yapılıyor, lütfen bekleyin");
    monthNames = [
        "Oca", "Şub", "Mar",
        "Nis", "May", "Haz", "Tem",
        "Ağu", "Eyl", "Eki",
        "Kas", "Ara"
    ];
    date = new Date($("#dob").val());
    day = date.getDate();
    monthIndex = date.getMonth();
    year = date.getFullYear();
    finalDate = day+' '+monthNames[monthIndex]+' '+year;
    var fid = '';
    $.each(fids, function(k,v) {
        fid += '&node[field_fotograflar][und]['+k+'][fid]='+v;
    });
    var cat = '';
    $('#oyuncuKategori input:checked').each(function(k,v) {
        cat += '&node[field_kategorisi][und]['+k+']='+$(this).attr('id');
    });
    $.ajax({
        url:'http://www.rejicast.com/services/node/'+nid+'.json',
        type:'put',
        dataType:'json',
        beforeSend: function(r) {
            r.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", localStorage.token)
        },
        data:'node[type]=oyuncu&node[title]='+encodeURIComponent($("#name").val())+'&node[language]=und&node[field_tc_kimlik_no][und][0][value]='+encodeURIComponent($("#tckn").val())+'&node[field_sgk_durumu][und][value]='+encodeURIComponent($("#sgk option:selected").val())+cat+'&node[field_telefon][und][0][value]='+encodeURIComponent($("#tel").val())+'&node[field_telefon_2][und][0][value]='+encodeURIComponent($("#tel2").val())+'&node[field_adres][und][0][value]='+encodeURIComponent($("#address").val())+'&node[field_yasadigi_sehir][und][value]='+encodeURIComponent($("#city option:selected").val())+'&node[field_e_posta][und][0][value]='+encodeURIComponent($("#email").val())+'&node[field_cinsiyet][und][value]='+encodeURIComponent($("#gender option:selected").val())+'&node[field_gogus][und][value]='+$("#chest option:selected").val()+'&node[field_bel][und][value]='+$("#waist option:selected").val()+'&node[field_kalca][und][value]='+$("#thigh option:selected").val()+'&node[field_dogum_tarihi][und][0][value][date]='+finalDate+'&node[field_boy][und][value]='+encodeURIComponent($("#height option:checked").val())+'&node[field_kilo][und][value]='+encodeURIComponent($("#weight option:selected").val())+'&node[field_goz_rengi][und][value]='+encodeURIComponent($("#eyecolour option:selected").val())+'&node[field_ten_rengi][und][value]='+encodeURIComponent($("#skincolour option:selected").val())+'&node[field_ayak_no][und][value]='+encodeURIComponent($("#shoesize option:selected").val())+'&node[field_egitim_duzeyi][und][value]='+encodeURIComponent($("#education option:selected").val())+'&node[field_oyunculuk_egitimleri][und][0][value]='+encodeURIComponent($("#training").val())+'&node[field_diller][und][0][value]='+encodeURIComponent($("#languages").val())+'&node[field_beceriler][und][0][value]='+encodeURIComponent($("#skills").val())+'&node[field_kisisel][und][0][value]='+encodeURIComponent($("#personal").val())+'&node[field_videolar][und][0][video_url]='+encodeURIComponent($(".videolink").val())+'&node[field_videolar][und][0][description]='+encodeURIComponent($(".videodesc").val())+'&node[field_yapim_yili][und][value]='+encodeURIComponent(finalDate)+'&node[field_okudum_anladim][und][value]='+encodeURIComponent($(".privacy").is(':selected')?1:0),
        success:function(data) {
            ActivityIndicator.hide();
            navigator.notification.alert("Kaydınız başarıyla düzenlendi", function() {return;}, "Face in Cast", "Tamam");
        },
        error:function(xhr,status,message) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log(status);
            console.log(message);
            navigator.notification.alert("Eksik bırakılan alan var, lütfen doldurup tekrar deneyin.", function(){return;}, "Hata", "Tamam");
        }
    });
});
```

UPDATE:

[image: my services settings screenshot]
[image: my resources screenshot]

Comment: What's the machine name and path for your Services endpoint? In your code, replace `services` with the aforementioned path and you should be all set. Do that for all of them except the token retrieval, because `services/session/token` is the correct path to use.

Comment: @tyler.frankenstein they are both "services". Besides, all of them (except edit) are already working.

Comment: @tyler.frankenstein please see my screenshots above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the alias and it worked :) Apparently resource name doesn't work if I assign an alias to it.